If $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is measurable, what can we say about $f \, \chi_\Omega$, $|f| \, \chi_\Omega$ and $|f|^p \, \chi_\Omega$?
Consider the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ denote an arbitrary non-empty open set. Furthermore, $\chi_\Omega$ stands for the characteristic function of $\Omega$ and $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ is an arbitrary element.
Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be a measurable function. My questions are pretty simple and follow below.
Questions.

Can we guarantee that $f \, \chi_\Omega : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a measurable function ?
Can we guarantee that $|f| \, \chi_\Omega : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a measurable function?
Can we guarantee that $|f|^p \, \chi_\Omega : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a measurable function ?

My thoughts. I believe that I can answer question $1.$ by using the fact that the product of measurable functions is measurable (see this post). On the other hand, I believe that question $2.$ also has an affirmative answer that follows from combining the facts that the absolute value of a measurable function is again measurable (see this post) and the fact that the product of measurable functions is again measurable. Finally, question $3.$ also has an affirmative answer which is obtained by using the fact that any power of a measurable function is again measurable (see this post).
Can anyone confirm if my approach to this question is valid ?
Thanks for any help in advance.

It's entirely correct
